# "Creator" pattern to configure inherited objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, prototype, factory, builder

I have the following object structure:

```
class Annotation;
class LabelAnnotation: inherits Annotation;
class TextAnnotation: inherits LabelAnnotation;
```

I would like to use "creator" objects to do some initialization on these object (This initialization depends on external settings so I don't want to do it in the constructor of these objects.)

In particular, when creating a LabelAnnotation I would like to do:

```
fontSize = AppDefaults.fontSize
```

So I'm writing a "creator":

```
class LabelAnnotationCreator {
    LabelAnnotation create() {
        annotation = LabelAnnotation()
        annotation.fontSize = AppDefaults.fontSize
        return annotation;
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to create a TextAnnotationCreator. This is where I'm stuck: I can't use the LabelAnnotationCreator because it would create an instance of a LabelAnnotation, but on the other hand, I want to benefit from the initialization performed by the LabelAnnotationCreator.

```
class TextAnnotationCreator {
    TextAnnotation create() {
        annotation = TextAnnotation()
        // I'm stuck here:
        // can't do LabelAnnotationCreator().create()… ???
        return annotation;
    }
}
```

Obviously, this isn't the right pattern but I'm not sure how to find the correct one.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to benefit from the initialization of LabelAnnotationCreator object?

Comment: annotation.fontSize = AppDefaults.fontSize

Comment: do both of TextAnnotationCreator class and LavelAnnotationCreator have fontSize property?

Comment: The fontSize property is not in the creator class, it's on the LabelAnnotation class. The TextAnnotation class has it as well because it inherits the LabelAnnotation class.

Answer (score 0):

what do you think about this:

```
class TextAnnotation {
    private final int someOtherArgs;
    private final int fontSize;

    public TextAnnotation(LabelAnnotation labelAnnotation, int someOtherArgs) {
        this(someOtherArgs, labelAnnotation.getFontSize());
    }

    public TextAnnotation(int someOtherArgs, int fontSize) {
        this.someOtherArgs= someOtherArgs;
        this.fontSize = fontSize;
    }
}
```

create a constructor on `TextAnnotation` that builds a object from a `LabelAnnotation` configuration. Then you can use it like this:

```
TextAnnotation text = new TextAnnotation(someArgs,fontSize);
```

or using your creator

```
class TextAnnotationCreator {
    TextAnnotation create() {
        return 
           new TextAnnotation(
               new LabelAnnotationCreator().create(),
               someOtherArgs
           );
    }
}
```

Comment: These decorators are really elegant but unfortunately, I do need the LabelAnnotation and TextAnnotation as concrete types.

Comment: I changed my answer. Now i suggest to use a constructor that builds an object from other object configuration